# Flow of charges inside a battery

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current

I am having confusion about the flow of charges inside a battery which is connected to Circuit.

Question is, do charges move from one end to another through the battery? If yes, how? Do they move from lower to higher potential? If yes, how?

Comment: have a look http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html  and here  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/battery.html   .

Answer (score 2):

In a galvanic cell there are three charge motions that need to be considered. The chemistry varies from battery to battery, so I will describe the traditional zinc anode and copper cathode. Similar concepts apply for most batteries, but the details differ considerably.

The current from the wire enters the anode of the cell, which in this case is made of zinc. This zinc is immersed in a solution of zinc sulfate.  At the surface of the zinc a chemical reaction occurs wherein metallic zinc (uncharged) on the surface of the metal is converted to zinc ions (positive charge) in the solution. Excess electrons are left behind in the metal creating a negative terminal. This reaction is energetically favorable and will occur even against a voltage gradient, and this is (one half of) the source of the battery’s power.

Now, between the anode and the cathode there is no metal. Instead, the current flows in the form of motion of sulfate ions through an electrolyte. There is a barrier which prevents motion of the metal ions, and only allows motion of sulfate ions. These just move passively, by Ohm’s law and by diffusion. In the solution the zinc ions must be paired with sulfate ions so there is a deficit of sulfate ions at the zinc surface which drives this current.

Finally, at the cathode there is a chemical reaction where (positive) copper ions in the copper sulfate solution are converted into copper metal on the electrode. This conversion leaves the electrode with an excess positive charge. As before this reaction is energetically favorable and drives the other half of the battery’s power.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by a reaction being energetically favourable?You didn't answer according to my question.

Comment: I did answer your question. What part do you think I missed? “Energetically favorable” means that energy is released from the reaction as opposed to energy being required by the reaction.

Answer (score 0):

When you discharge the current moves from + to -, when you charge the go in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

A battery is a reservoir of electrons at a potential difference relative to another reservoir of seemingly positive charges (ions) separated by a distance, hence potential (so the electrons don't flow through but in and out of the different potential regions). When you link both reservoirs through their terminals you get electrons flow from the electrons reservoir to the other equally positive reservoir in the attempt to neutralize the system and obey the attraction law. By electrons flow, this means the already existing electrons in the conductor is pushed ahead, and this ripples down the wire all the way to it end connected to the positive side. Spontaneously everything seems to move from a higher to a lower potential, and in the case of a battery or electricity flow in general, the high potential region is always the region with greater negativity.